# Окончание числительных во всплывающей подсказке ссылки закрытия вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[image: 4 дополнительных голосов необходимо, чтобы закрыть вопрос]

Должно быть:

> 4 дополнительных голоса необходимо, чтобы закрыть вопрос

---

[image: 3 дополнительных голосов необходимо, чтобы закрыть вопрос]

Должно быть:

> 3 дополнительных голоса необходимо, чтобы закрыть вопрос

---

[image: 2 дополнительных голосов необходимо, чтобы закрыть вопрос]

Должно быть:

> 2 дополнительных голоса необходимо, чтобы закрыть вопрос

---

[image: Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос, необходимо еще 1 голосов]

Должно быть:

> Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос, необходим еще 1 голос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал единообразные [варианты](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262842?key=b39b6ec73437e65b022877ebb4d5c322):

- one

  > Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос, необходим ещё $numVotes$ голос
- few

  > Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос, необходимо ещё $numVotes$ голоса
- many

  > Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос, необходимо ещё $numVotes$ голосов

Answer (score -1):

Мое первое предложение на meta

```
Для закрытия вопроса, не хватает $numVotes$ голоса.
```

Тогда будет работать как для 1, так и для 2 и больше.

Comment: Во-первых, падежи. Для 2 и больше тут нужно "голосОВ". Во-вторых, лишняя запятая, но это мелочь по сравнению с первым :)

Comment: Ну почему.. не  хвастает одного голоса; не хватает два голоса.

Comment: Вот-с, уведомляю вас, что это неправильно :) Не хватает **двух голосов**. Не хватает "чего?". Родительный падеж. Но если сомневаетесь в моих познаниях (имеете полное право), есть [rus.SE](http://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @D-side каких каких сов?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33140011#33140011